# Eclipse importación de librerías

Tags: java

Esta claro que se pueden importar librerías externas a eclipse y sé cómo se hace, la cuestión es cómo hacer para no estar cada vez que creo un proyecto estar importando librerías externas que automáticamente sirvan para todos mis proyectos.

¿Es capaz de hacerlo el programa?

Answer (score 1):

La respuesta corta a tu pregunta es: [Maven](https://maven.apache.org/).

---

Ahora voy a expilcarme un poco.

Entre las miles de cosas que esta joya hace, creo que la mas popular es la de importación de librerías a partir de repositorios. Como puedes crear tus propios repositorios, creando una dependencia personalizada en uno de ellos (puede ser local o remoto) tendrás todas las librerías que quieras listas para todos los proyectos que crees.

Pero para ello primero tienes que saber algo de como funciona Maven, los repos y las dependencias.

**NOTA:** *es importante tener en cuenta que los proyectos no comparten librerias.*

---

## INSTALACION EN ECLIPSE

La mayoria de las versiones de Eclipse vienen con maven integrado, aun asi [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8620127/maven-in-eclipse-step-by-step-installation) puedes encontrar los pasos que resumo para instalarlo manualmente.

- Abrir Eclipse
- Vé a Ayuda -> Eclipse Marketplace
- Busca "Maven"
- Presiona el boton de instalar para la seccion "Maven Integration for Eclipse" (integracion Maven en Eclipse)
- Sigue los pasos que se te iran indicando.

---

## CREAR / CONVERTIR PROYECTOS

- Crear nuevo proyecto Maven <kbd>Menu Archivo</kbd> > <kbd>Nuevo</kbd> > <kbd>Otros</kbd> > <kbd>New Maven Project (Nuevo Proyecto Maven)</kbd>
- También puedes hacer click derecho en tus proyectos existentes y convertirlos a proyectos maven.

---

## FICHERO POM

La base de los proyectos Maven es el fichero (o ficheros) `pom.xml`. Allí, aparte de muchas otras cosas que iras viendo, podrás definir los `<repository>` (repositorios) desde donde se descargaran las `<dependency>` que tiene tu proyecto, o sea, las librerías.

Un `pom.xml` recien creado es algo así:

```
<project 
      xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>TestMaven</groupId>
  <artifactId>testMaven</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
</project>
```

## IMPORTAR LIBRERIAS

Aquí ya llegamos a tu pregunta, ¿qué pasa cuando necesitas alguna librería? Vamos a poner por ejemplo que vas a hacer una aplicación de control de acceso y para las fechas necesitas `JodaTime`. Casi todo está **https://mvnrepository.com**, pero una simple [**búsqueda**](https://www.google.es/#safe=active&q=joda+time+maven) te dará lo que necesites en cada momento.

Cuando llegues a la versión que necesites podrás copiar el código, en el caso de Joda Time 2.9.4:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/joda-time/joda-time -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
    <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
    <version>2.9.4</version>
</dependency>
```

---

**NOTAS SOBRE LAS VERSIONES:**

- cambiando el número de versión puedes importar versiones antiguas o nuevas de cualquier libreria.
- **SOLO MAVEN 2** deprecated en Maven 3

  - `<version>LATEST</version>`
  - `<version>RELEASE</version>`

---

Ahora, que haces con eso? Pues te vas al `pom.xml` del proyecto (si tienes varios modulos pues al que interese) y necesitaras crear una parte en el pom que maneje tus dependencias. Para no alargarme mucho, tu pom quedara aproximadamente así:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>TestMaven</groupId>
    <artifactId>testMaven</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/joda-time/joda-time -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
                <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
                <version>2.9.4</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
</project>
```

## INSTALACION Y BUILD DEL PROYECTO

Y por fin llegamos al final `;P` ejecutar el proyecto, como he dicho al pricipio maven hace muchas cosas y tambien el build del proyecto, para ello tienes que crear un perfil para que tu programa corra, indicandole que *goals* debe cumplir, para empezar te recomiendo `clean install` y marcar la casilla de skip tests:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Haces run y veras como Eclipse y maven empiezan a hacer sus cositas juntos:

```
[INFO] Downloaded: libreriaxxxxx-1.0.jar (12 KB at 29.6 KB/sec)
[INFO] Installing C:\xxxx\testMaven-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar to C:\xxx\TestMaven\testMaven\0.0.1-SNAPSHOT\testMaven-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
[INFO] Installing C:\xxx\eclipse_workspace\testMaven\pom.xml to C:\\xxx\TestMaven\testMaven\0.0.1-SNAPSHOT\testMaven-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.pom
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 33.270 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2016-06-30T15:52:54+01:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 9M/76M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Listo, ya tienes tu aplicación corriendo con las librerias que te interesen y sin tenerte que preocupar por importarlas manualmente.

---

**PD:** si tienes alguna duda, no dudes en preguntar

Answer (score 1):

Como alternativa a maven puedes mantener un repositorio con todas tus librerías y crear archivos **`.userlibraries`** con ellas.

Puedes incluso crear un archivo que importe todas las librerías del repositorio.

Por ejemplo:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<eclipse-userlibraries version="2">
      <library name="someLib1.0" systemlibrary="false">
           <archive path="/your/path/to/jar/someLib.jar" source="your/path/to/jar/someLib.jar"/>
      </library>
      <library name="anotherLib1.0" systemlibrary="false">
               <archive path="/your/path/to/jar/anotherLib.jar" source="your/path/to/jar/anotherLib.jar"/>
      </library>
</eclipse-userlibraries>
```

Luego cuando importas un proyecto en el workspace vas a:

`Java Build Path > Add Libraries > User Libraries > Import`y eliges el `.userlibraries` específico

Una buena manera es definir un archivo `.userlibraries` con las dependencias a las librerias comunmente utilizadas por tus proyectos y luego otros `.userlibraries` independientes con librerías de uso particular de cada proyecto.

La ventaja de esto no es mas que evitar el agregado manual, sobre todo cuando un proyecto utiliza muchas librerías, asi como tambien mantener organizado la estructura de dependencias a librerias externas de cada proyecto.

Espero te sirva,

Saludos

Answer (score 0):

> cada vez que creo un proyecto estar importando librerias externas, que automaticamente sirvan para todos mis proyectos

La pregunta es ambigua. Si lo que quieres es tener la facilidad, dentro de una instancia de Eclipse, de que cuando creas nuevos proyectos Java incluir un conjunto de `jar`s externos [*] pretederminados, sin necesidad de seleccionarlos de a uno...  En tal caso, lo que te conviene es definir una "User library" (`Preferences -> Java -> BuildPath -> User libraries` )
Le pones el nombre que quieras y le agregas los jars externos que quieras.
Luego, en tu proyecto Java agregas esta UserLibrary en el BuildPath (también puedes hacerlo al momento de la creación, el wizard te da la oportunidad de hacerlo).

[*] Por "jar externo" entiendo lo que entiende Eclipse: un jar que está en una ubicación "externa" (no en el workspace), normalmente en otro lugar del disco. No necesariamente significa un "third party" jar (es decir, una libreria generada por otros desarrolladores, y disponible en repositorios públicos). Para esto último, Maven o Gradle pueden servirte.

Comment: Muchas gracias a los dos.....

Comment: De nada. Si eres nuevo: http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

Primero y antes de nada debemos crear un nuevo proyecto java. Seguidamente clickamos con el botón derecho sobre el y seleccionamos Build Path / Configure Build Path:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Seguidamente nos aparecerá una ventana emergente donde deberemos dirigirnos a la pestaña Libraries. En esta ventana podremos observar que actualmente se encuentran las librerías propias de java (el JRE). Ya solo nos quedaría clickar en el botón Add External Jars… añadir la o las librerías necesarias y pulsar en aceptar:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Finalmente os añado una captura de ejemplo de como importar una librería externa a una clase:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]