# No se importan las librerias en eclipse, ¿que deberia hacer?

Tags: java, java-swing, eclipse

resulta que cuando intento importar las librerías java y javax me aparecer que no existen y debo crearlas

tengo instalado jdk y los demás componentes bien, pero este error solo me lo arroja en eclipse, ya que en netbeans no tengo el mismo inconveniente, que debería hacer?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

ese es el error que me arroja

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Puedes ir al Build Path, entrar en addLibrary; una vez dentro, pulsar en Installed JREs y a partir de ahí añadir de nuevo tu librería. Es lo único que se me ocurre...Saludos. Te dejo un enlace que a lo mejor puede ayudarte: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/15479/eclipse-importaci%C3%B3n-de-librer%C3%ADas